# solve this riddle based on foundational logics and proofs in descrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

there was this question in the book "Discrete Mathematics" by kenneth rosen
each inhabitant of a remote village always tells the truth or always lies .A villager will only give a "yes" or "no" response to a question a tourist asks. suppose you are a tourist visiting this area and come to a fork in the road. One branch leads to the ruins you want to visit ; the other branch leads deep into the jungle .A villager is standing at the fork in the road . What one question can you ask the villager to determine which branch to take?

Now the problem that i am facing with this question is that in the answer key the solution to this question is given as: if i were to ask you whether the right branch leads to the ruins would you answer yes.

But how would the response to this question help me determine which branch to take because if he is a liar he would respond negatively even if the right branch actually leads to the ruins , as he is a liar he has a tendency to give a wrong response even to that question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, and because Labyrinth came out in the mid-eighties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the "double negative", effectively treating his answer with an XOR that will give you the right answer. Since you know the villagers will always do the same thing, you can use his own knowledge about his own potential answer to trick him into giving you the correct answer.

There are 4 ways this can go down. You have the case where the right path is the correct one and the case where it is the wrong one. Then you have the case where you have a villager that always tells the truth, and the case where he always lies. Multiply to get 4 combinations.

- If the right path is correct, and the villager always tells the truth:

  - If you were to ask him if the right path is correct he would say "Yes" (because he tells the truth)
  - So he will say "Yes" to the question of whether he would say "Yes"
- If the right path is incorrect, and the villager always tells the truth:

  - If you were to ask him if the right path is correct he would say "No"
  - Consequently he will answer "No" to the question of whether he would answer the first question with "Yes".
- If, on the other hand the villager always lies, and the path is correct:

  - If you were to ask him if the right path is correct he would've said "No"
  - So when you ask him "Would you have said Yes?", he will lie, and say "Yes".
- And if the path is incorrect and the villager always lies:

  - If you were to ask him if the right path is correct he would've said "Yes"
  - So when you ask him "Would you have said Yes?", he will lie, and say "No".

So here are the outcomes in a table:

```
Path      Villager      Final answer
Correct   Truth         Yes
Incorrect Truth         No
Correct   Lie           Yes
Incorrect Lie           No
```

As you can see, the answer will in fact match the path correctness.

Answer (score 1):

One good question is "If I asked what road leads to freedom, what path would the other kind of villager point to?"

In this case both kind of villagers would point at the wrong road.

Comment: @srishti77714 You're one to ask for proper english! :P